# Is any telegram from the Pacific Scandal preserved?

Tags: political-history, canada

Are there any existing telegrams of communications between the various members of Canada's [Pacific Scandal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacific_Scandal)? If so, where can I find them? I want to know how all the different players acted, and what they did once the allegations were made.